# PHP turn an array with a single massive element into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a ton of trouble with an API that is returning an array with a single massive element that I need to split up. This has proven to be a tough nut to crack.

```
 $CrappyArray = array([TheSingleElement]=>header1-header2-header3-value1.1-value1.2-value1.3-value2.1-value2.2-value2.3);
```

I've tried using just a regular explode.

```
$BetterArray= explode('-', $CrappyArray['TheSingleElement']);
print_r($BetterArray);
```

Unfortunately, that just returns:

```
Array ([0]=>header1 [1]=>header2 [2]=>header3 [3]value1.1 [4]value1.2 [5]value1.3 [6]value2.1 [7]value2.2 [8]value2.3)
```

This isn't any better. What I need is:

```
Array (
[0]=>Array ([0]=>header1 [1]=>header2 [2]=>header3) 
[1]=>Array ([0]=>value1.1 [1]value2.2 [2]value2.3) 
[2]=>Array ([0]=>value2.1 [1]=>value2.2 [2]=>value2.3)
)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `array_slice` after that.

Comment: Does the `$CrappyArray` always come with 9 elements? Since `[1]=>Array ([0]=>value1.1 [1]value2.2 [2]value2.3)` and `[2]=>Array ([0]=>value2.1 [1]=>value2.2 [2]=>value2.3)` look similar to me and no simple logic can separate these two.

Comment: HA, array_slice didn't do it, but the manual page for it linked me to array_chunk, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
$BetterArray = array_chunk($BetterArray, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bassicaly, you want to parse that ugly string into tokens first, and then walk thru tokens and build a new array.

If explode is not enough (but it looks fine for now), try preg_match_all. It is a bit harder to use, but it is much more powerful.

When you have ugly string as array of tokens, simply walk it using foreach or whatever suits you and build structure you are looking for.

I do not think there is an easier solution than this.